# Chameleon Particles: Space Weapons?

Tags: weapon-mass-destruction, astrophysics, space-warfare

**Dark Energy** is a force said to be responsible for cosmic expansion, and one of the theorised carriers of this force is the **Chameleon Particle**. To describe its effects, due to its non-linear self-interaction, it has a variable level of interaction. In places where the density of matter is relatively high, chameleon particles are **heavier**, interacts **very weakly** with other matter and only over **very short distances** (*in the range of less than 1mm*).

However, in inter-galactic space where matter density is extremely low, the particles are **lighter**, interact **much more strongly** with other matter and over **very large distances** (*over 100,000+ parsecs*). This means that the particles could be exerting a force that is pushing the universe apart in outer space.

Here is a more detailed explanation: https://skyandtelescope.org/astronomy-news/is-dark-energy-a-chameleon-0824201523/

Assume a world where this theory is correct, and this elusive particle exists. Additionally, assume that they can be mass produced. Could this be used in outer space (*where density of surroundings is very low*) as a weapon to concentrate the effects of pre-existing dark energy, "pushing" planets and stars from a distance? If not, is there any other way to use them in space for military uses?

Note: *This is completely different from my original question. That one referred to space constructs. This is another application. Also, as a side note, I already fixed the old question, so can someone do me a favour to help reopen it?*

Comment: Hmmm. The universe is expanding only over very large distances. The universe is *not* expanding over distances of the order of 100 kiloparsecs; closeby objects (such as the galaxies in the Local Group) *are not* going away in the deep dark yonder. Whatever dark energy is or does, it is only acting over distances of more than a megaparsec or so.

Comment: "Additionally, assume that they can be mass produced." Interesting turn of words. Should it be more accurately stated "Additionally, assume that they can be DARK-mass produced."? But weaponizing dark chocolate, now THAT is another completely different concept. Cocoa mass is something we CAN mass produce,

Comment: If you are producing it in quantity, then you are not in a low-density environment, by definition. So how do you get the effects of this particle in a low-density environent, using a high-density concentration of these particles? You might push galaxies away but by the very nature of the concept, you can not use a low-density construct in a high-denisty format. That is, how do you concentrate enough of it in one spot to selectively target just a planet, without it reverting to its high density properties?

Comment: How big should a chameleon sphere be to have the same pushing effect as the moon's can attract things? 1 meter, 100 meter, 1 kilometer? Half the moon's size? The size of a strawberry pie? Scales can greatly affect answers as having a weapon as big as a spaceship or only as the captain commanding it drastically changes its usability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:No expert:

I am unsure what you think the Expansion actually is. Kind of like people think the Big Bang was an Explosion even although it was an Expension of Space itself. And Time.

Dark Energy and Dark Matter act in a similar way. You see, everything is expanding away from Everything. It is like at the smallest scale, everything expands outwards. This is the reason why it looks like everything is expanding away from us. But from Andromeda, it would appear as if everything expands away from there. You as in you the person Observing are always the Center of the Expansion. Similar as to how YOU are the Center of the Universe because you can observe it in all directions equally.

In saying that, from what i understand, You do not expand with the Universe. Andromeda does not get bigger. (Again, no expert but this is how i understand it). What they do is create a Force on objects. At least in an Indirect way. The best i can say is that Dark Matter and Energy "Create space".

So with all of that in mind, i would guess a Weapon of this sort would not so much push against anything than just expand the space in its path. Which to us looks like it is being pushed away.

So as an answer, it is a "Yes but".

Comment: If you push it away faster than the speed of light, there is nothing they can do that will catch up to you.,,, Wait - nothing can travel faster than the speed of light .... wait -  if the universe keeps expanding eventually it will expand faster than the speed of light ,., wait - then nothing is traveing away from each other at all .... wait - I can't see it any more it is traveling away faster than the light being emitted from it towards me ..... wait-  now THAT is some red shift ..., Yep, that is some 'Yes but'!!!!!!!